# Are checked guard parameter packs cause of ill-formed programs?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

More than once (even on SO) I've seen code like this:

```
template<typename U, typename... G, typename T = Traits<U>>
struct {
    static_assert(sizeof...(G) == 0, "!");
    // ...
};
```

Or this:

```
template<typename T, typename... G, typename = std::enable_if_t<condition<T>>
void func(T &&t) {
    static_assert(sizeof...(G) == 0, "!");
    // ....
}
```

The intent was to avoid users break the rule of the game by doing something like this:

```
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<T, int>>
void func(T &&t) {
    // ....
}

// ...

func<int&, void>(my_int);
```

With the guard parameter pack, the defaulted value cannot be overridden.
On the other side, the check on the size avoids pollution of the specializations with useless parameters.

Anyway, because of [[temp.res/8]](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8), we have that:

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>   [...]
>   - every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack, or
>   [...]

Therefore, are the programs that contain the above mentioned snippets ill-formed or not?

Comment: Yes. Which is why experienced TMP'lers would use a class template that takes both the size of the pack and `T` to determine the `static_assert` condition. (Although I don't know if experienced TMP'lers would actually go with this approach in the first place.)

Comment: I don't see the point in using the parameter pack in the first place, you can just use `template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<condition<T>, int> = 0>` which cannot be circumvented by the user and can be used in on-off SFINAE as well.

Comment: @Corristo, never seem code like that. Nice trick!

Comment: @Corristo I suspect you didn't get the point of the question. It is not about how to write sfinae expressions.

Comment: @skypack Yes I know, but I wanted to emphasize that template `<typename T, std::enable_if_t<condition<T>, int> = 0>` is superior to parameter packs in every way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "trick" results in an ill formed program, no diagnostic required.

The standard states it clearly in the section you quoted.