# Are checked guard parameter packs cause of ill-formed programs in case of specializations?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, language-lawyer, variadic-templates

This is a follow-up on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076078/are-checked-guard-parameter-packs-cause-of-ill-formed-programs) question.

Consider the following code:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename... P, typename U = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
void f() { static_assert(sizeof...(P) == 0, "!"); }

int main() {
    f<int>();
}
```

It compiles, but according to [[temp.res]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8) it is ill-formed, no diagnostic required because of:

> every valid specialization of a variadic template requires an empty template parameter pack

Now consider this slightly different example:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename... P, typename U = std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral<T>::value>>
void f() { static_assert(sizeof...(P) == 0, "!"); }

template<>
void f<int, int>() { }

int main() {
    f<int, int>();
}
```

In this case a valid full explicit specialization exists for which the parameter pack is not empty.
Does this suffice to say that the code is no longer ill-formed?

---

<sub>Note: I'm not looking for alternative ways like putting the `std::enable_if_t` in the return type or similar.</sub>

Comment: You're saying that `static_assert` makes the `f` function template specialization **invalid** in case of `sizeof...(P)!=0`? Very interesting question!

Comment: @W.F. Yeah. The linked question contains the details for the first example. I'm glad you like it. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[temp.res]/8 talks about *template-declaration*s, not the entity. That is, it talks about primary templates and partial specializations *individually*; these "templates" must *each* have a valid specialization subject to the rules. Otherwise, the first bullet in that paragraph would have to be interpreted in the same manner, which definitely doesn't give it its intended meaning.

```
template <typename T>
void f() {T+0;} // wouldn't be allowed to diagnose this, because there could be an 
                // explicit specialization that doesn't contain this statement...?
```

Comment: Really interesting. I'll look over the standard once again. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let's not go that far. `template<class T> void f() { 1 + nullptr; }` would do it. And I believe your example actually cannot be diagnosed because `f<const int&>()` is valid :)

Comment: @T.C. Is it? The initializer is governed by [expr.type.conv]/3, which precludes reference types by its phrasing; and /2 precludes reference types explicitly for the `()` initializer, so that feels consistent. I also don't see how you can create an lvalue reference and yield it as a prvalue.

Comment: @T.C. "Let's not go that far." Did you just mean the example, or is something else looking dubious? Btw., I chose this example because it looked interesting, and apparently it is :-)

Comment: The example. Assuming N4140 is what you are referring to (since [expr.type.conv] only has two paragraphs these days): "similarly" clearly doesn't refer to p2 because p3 applies to braced-init-lists generally, and `T{1,2,3}` is nothing similar to `T()`. The "prvalue" part is just broken - see CWG 1521.

Comment: In any event, `f<const int>()` is valid :P Dunno how I went straight to references...

Comment: @T.C. Right, I didn't have the WD at hand.

Comment: @T.C. I did edit that comment; p3 refers to p1, and I was gonna edit and explain that it is consistent wrt to the `{}` case, but 5 mins were over.

Comment: OTOH you can't value-initialize a reference but you can do `const int& i{};`, so consistency goes both ways :)