# Base class constructor not called?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14

I was searching the cause of a really strange bug in my program. I discovered that strangely, the base class constructor is not called for some reason. Here is the code to reproduce:

```
struct Parent {
    Parent() : test{9} {}

    int test;
};

template<typename T>
struct Child : T {
    Child() = default;

    // Will obviously not call this one
    template<typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Args) == 9999>* = nullptr>
    Child(Args&&... args);
};

int main() {
    Child<Parent> test;
    std::cout << "This is a test: " << test.test << std::endl;
}
```

In my case, the program simply crash or print random values.

If I change the child class to this, the constructor is called:

```
template<typename T>
struct Child : T {
    Child() = default;
};
```

Same thing for that, the constructor is still called:

```
template<typename T>
struct Child : T {
    Child() {}

    // Will obviously not call this one
    template<typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Args) == 9999>* = nullptr>
    Child(Args&&... args);
};
```

But with the first definition, the parent constructor is not called. **I even tried to mark the parent constructor as deleted**, but it still compile and crash!

Here's the code with the deleted constructor:

```
struct Parent {
    Parent() = delete;

    int test;
};

template<typename T>
struct Child : T {
    Child() = default;

    // Will obviously not call this one
    template<typename... Args, std::enable_if_t<sizeof...(Args) == 9999>* = nullptr>
    Child(Args&&... args);
};

int main() {
    Child<Parent> test;
    std::cout << "This is a test: " << test.test << std::endl;
}
```

I'm using visual studio 2015 update 3.

Comment: `std::enable_if_t<false>` should be a hard error, not a substitution failure.

Comment: indeed you are right. I'll check if it still happening without that.

Comment: Doesn't the code cause undefined behaviour? Compare with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40842044/are-checked-guard-parameter-packs-cause-of-ill-formed-programs-in-case-of-specia)

Comment: [Works fine in GCC and Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbb5446f3ca102f8)

Comment: Seems to also work on Microsoft's online compiler: http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/

Comment: @TartanLlama: Only if said template were to be instantiated :-)

Comment: @AndyG I tried my code with the deleted constructor on the web compiler. It seems to reject it as it's supposed to. In 2015 update 3, it accept the code. Seems like I hit quite a bug...

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot: Indeed it appears so. With all the SFINAE fixes that have finally made it into VS, I suppose it's fixed.

Comment: Compiling with /W4 gives "warning C4700: uninitialized local variable 'test' used", and looking at the disassembly it stores the `ecx` value passed into main into `test.test`.  Definitely a bug.

Comment: @AndyG hmm... It don't seems to be related to SFINAE at all... I just tried without the `enable_if`, and it compile fine even if the parent constructor is deleted. Seems like defaulted default constructor + presence of a variadic constructor = parent construcor not called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bug in that compiler.

If you upgrade your version of Visual Studio 2015 that should work.

[Microsoft's online compiler](http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/) at version 19.10.24631.0 (x86) appears to produce the correct output.

[GCC 6.2.0 and Clang 3.8.0 also appear to produce the correct output](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbb5446f3ca102f8)

Comment: I'm using the latest version of 2015... seems like I'll have to upgrade to 2017 then... thanks for your help.