# SFINAE fallback when a function does not exist

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, enable-if

I'm currently trying to implement a `toString` function which calls `.toString()` or `std::to_string()` depending on which is available for the deduced type

So far I have this working snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template <class T>
auto toString(const T& obj)
        -> decltype(obj.toString(), std::string())
{
  return obj.toString();
}

template <class T>
auto toString(const T& obj)
        -> decltype(std::to_string(obj), std::string())
{
  return std::to_string(obj);
}

template <class T>
auto toString(const T& obj)
        -> decltype(std::string(obj))
{
  return std::string(obj);
}

class Foo{
public:
  std::string toString() const {
    return "Hello";
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo bar;
  std::cout << toString(bar);
  std::cout << toString(5);
  std::cout << toString("Hello const char*");
}
```

Now I want to insert a `static_assert` when no overload from those above is viable, because the default GCC error message for older GCC versions is not very informative.

How can I check if neither `.toString()` nor `std::to_string()` are possible for `T`?

So far I found no way to check if something is *not* present, only the other way around. I hope someone has an idea how to solve this and thanks for your time.

Comment: `decltype(std::to_string(obj), std::string())` - TIL. But you should `void` the first expression. An overloaded comma operator from a naughty user can mess up your SFINAE

Comment: @max66 - No point in repeating yourself. And the OP's version will work with anything that is convertible to a `std::string` while fixing the return type of the function. Quite clever.

Comment: @StoryTeller - you're right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `static_assert` with a custom error message:

```
class Dummy
{
public:
    std::string toString() const;    
private:
    Dummy() = default;
};

template <typename... Ts>
auto toString(Ts...)
{
    static_assert(std::is_same<std::tuple<Ts...>, std::tuple<Dummy>>::value, "neither std::to_str nor member toString() exists");
    return "";
}
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/10276312171354c1)

Comment: Thanks, excactly what i wanted. But why is this one not chosen over the other options?

Comment: @W.F. in which way?

Comment: @W.F. does "valid specialization" mean "no static_assert is triggered"?

Comment: cf. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40076078/are-checked-guard-parameter-packs-cause-of-ill-formed-programs

Answer (score 8):

You need to introduce an overload that is worse than every other that you currently have, and delete it. You don't need to check if neither of the string functions exist that way.

A popular way to do this is to use C style variadic arguments:

```
std::string toString(...) = delete;
```

Comment: Thanks, TIL you can delete a non member function :). It's the easiest answer but i prefer @m.s 's answer because of the custom error message which is more expressive in this case.

Answer (score 4):

```
namespace details{
  template<template<class...> class, class, class...>
  struct can_apply : std::false_type{};

  template<template<class...> class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, std::void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...> : std::true_type{};
}
template<template<class...> class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;

template<class T>
using dot_toString_r = decltype(std::declval<T>().toString());

template<class T>
using can_dot_toString = can_apply<dot_toString_r, T>;
```

I leave `can_std_to_string` as an exercise.

If you lack `void_t` in your standard revision:

```
template<class...> struct voider { using type=void; };
template<class...Ts> using void_t = typename voider<Ts...>::type;
```

Which works even in early [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) compilers.